# Recordcount returns value of -1

Tags: sql, excel, record-count, vba

I have the below code which retrieves data correctly however always return a value of -1 for rs.RecordCount. Please assist.

```
    Sub TEST()

        Dim rs As Object
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        Dim SQLSTR As String, MYVAL As String
        MYVAL = InputBox("Enter Query")
        SQLSTR = " " & MYVAL & ""
        CONNECT_TO_DWHS
        rs.Open SQLSTR, PERSONALDBCONT

        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

            Debug.Print rs.RecordCount

        CLOSE_CONNECTION_TO_SQL


    End Sub
```

Comment: Try rs.MoveLast before you call rs.RecordCount

Comment: Hi @cboden, I get a 'rowset does not support fetching backwards' error

Comment: then use adOpenStatic (3) or adOpenKeyset (1) as third parameter when calling the rs.open method. If you have a reference to ADODB set in your project then you can use the named values ... if not simply use the numeric values in brackets or define a const for it.

Answer (score 1):

The ADO Recordsets will **ever** show this, until they've jumped to the end the first time. So just use rs.Movelast, then rs.MoveFirst.

Now it should be OK...

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi , I get a 'rowset does not support fetching backwards' error when i use rs.Movelast

Comment: Are you sure, that there is data? Check rs.EOF and rs.BOF. If both are TRUE than the recordset is empty...

Comment: Hi, there definitely is data. I'm familiar with rs.EOF and rs.BOF however I want to determine the total count rather than whether it's empty. So in future instances i can end the code when there is a count >= 1048576

Comment: @Krishn You could - just to see what happens  - do a `while not .EOF` loop with a `.MoveNext` as the only statement. I did a lot with Recordsets and never had a problem to retrieve their row count - if there were rows... That's why I asked...

Answer (score 1):

rs.CursorType = 3
Appears to work

Comment: Hi Krishn, you should mark your answer as accepted (check below the vote counter) to make clear, that this question has got an answer. If my answer wasn't the solution but helpful/useful in some way, it would be very nice to vote it up. The professionals giving answers on SO are hungry for reputation points. :-)